# Why is my async delegate in my loop not awaiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

Expected:
I need to run a task periodically.  I want the task to run, then wait for some delay, then run the task again... etc.

Actual:
I find that _loadingMethod is getting called/reentered.  I expected the while loop in the repeater to not comeback around until the await foo() statement completed.

Question:
Any ideas?  I feel like I am correctly awaiting all the way down the call stack.  Perhaps I missed something in a lambda or a delegate somewhere..?

```
    internal static CancellationTokenSource Repeat(Func<Task> foo, TimeSpan interval, int skipFirstFewIntervals = 0)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TaskWrapper.RunYetThrowOnMainThread( // kick off the loop
            async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(skipFirstFewIntervals * interval.Milliseconds); // initial delay (if any)
                while (await DelayOrCancel(interval, cancellationTokenSource.Token)) // loop forever or until cancel
                    try
                    {
                         await foo();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                                string msg = $"Failed while repeating: {foo.Method.Name}";
                        throw new Exception(msg, ex);
                    };
            });
         return cancellationTokenSource;
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DelayOrCancel(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
    {
        bool keepGoing;
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval, token); // this throws on cancel
            keepGoing = true;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            keepGoing = false; // kill the loop on cancel
        }
        return keepGoing;
    }
```

And the TaskWrapper class is below.

```
   internal static class TaskWrapper
   {
        internal static Task RunYetThrowOnMainThread(Action foo, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
            => RunYetThrowOnMainThread(() => Task.Run(foo), cancellationToken);

        internal static Task RunYetThrowOnMainThread(Func<Task> foo, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await foo();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = $"Failed at CPU bound task: {foo.Method.Name}";
                    ex.ThrowOnMainThread(msg);
                };
            });
        }
   }
```

And here is the Throw on ThrowOnMainThread ext method.  This way I can force the ex to surface even if I don't observe the task.

```
    internal static void ThrowOnMainThread(this Exception ex, string msg) => Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => throw new Exception(msg, ex));
```

At the calling layer it looks like this.

```
    internal CancellationTokenSource Start()
    {
        return Repeater.Repeat(LoadAsync, Cfg.LoadingInterval);
    }
```

You can see that the token source is passed up the call stack.

At the top layer I have something like.

```
        _incidentLoaderCanceller = _incidentLoader.Start();
```

Where _incidentLoaderCanceller is a CancellationTokenSource.

The _incidentLoader is a

```
internal class Loader<TData>
{
    private readonly Func<TData, Task<bool>> _loadingMethod;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Func<Exception, bool>> _exceptionHandlers;

    public Loader(Func<TData, Task<bool>> loadingMethod, IEnumerable<Func<Exception, bool>> exceptionHandlers)
    {
        _loadingMethod = loadingMethod.ThrowIfDefaultT();
        _exceptionHandlers = exceptionHandlers.ThrowIfDefaultT();
    }

    internal CancellationTokenSource Start()
    {
        return Repeater.Repeat(LoadAsync, Cfg.LoadingInterval);
    }

    private async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        ... // some looping over this guy LoadAsync(TData data)
    }

    ...

    private async Task<bool> LoadAsync(TData data)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            result = await _loadingMethod(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HandleOrRethrow(_exceptionHandlers);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The delegate you pass to `TaskWrapper.RunYetThrowOnMainThread` is (implicitly) async void. Make the method RunYetThrowOnMainThread take Func<Task> instead

Comment: Your implementation of RunYetThrowOnMainThread has issues to (also has an implcit async void delegate)

Comment: @DaveM What do you expect that to change?  The caller just ignores the `Task` returned by `RunYetThrowOnMainThread` anyway, so changing when that task completes, or what its result is, when no one is looking at it wouldn't matter.  While I personally don't like the design, the reality is that the top of the call stack here is `async void` by design.

Comment: I'm just point out things that I immediately see that are plain wrong without taking the time to dig deeply into this convoluted example. If had the complete solution I would post an answer.

Comment: @dFlat The only way you'll get some real help is if you can reduce this to a **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: @DaveM RunYetThrowOnMainThread() already has an overload that takes a Func<Task>.  You missed it.  It's posted above.  But it doesn't matter because that call is fire and forget.  It simply kicks off a while loop that runs until canceled.  Either way you slice it I need to await foo() and it appears to be getting reentered.  Please feel free to give constructive feedback.

Comment: @JSteward thanks for the advice.  I will rethink about how I can simplify and repose this question.  In the mean time if anyone else has constructive input please help.

Answer (score -1):

I found and fixed the issue.  Turns out my error handler was incorrectly marking a specific exception as handled when it shouldn't have.  The above code works for me.  It was hard fought to get it developed and tested.  Hopefully it will help someone else.